# Why is a wild card type argument not within bounds in wrapper around a selfreferring type

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface that contains methods that return or require instances of the imlementing type. To accomplish this I create a type variable of the form `U extends I<U>` to use as the return type. The intention of course being that `U` is the implementing class:

```java
interface SelfReferringInterface<U extends SelfReferringInterface<U>> {
}
```

Now I have an implementing class that contains an unrelated type variable:

```java
class RestrictingType<T> implements SelfReferringInterface<RestrictingType<T>> {

}
```

And a class that wraps around an instance of a `SelfReferringInterface`:

```java
class Wrapper<T extends SelfReferringInterface<T>> {
}
```

Somehow I get a type inference error for `Wrapper` types that take a wild card instance of `RestrictingType`:

```java
public class Main {

        public static void main(String... args) {
                // This type checks
                SelfReferringInterface<?> test1;
                // This too
                RestrictingType<?> test2;
                // And this
                Wrapper<RestrictingType<Object>> test3;
                // This fails
                Wrapper<RestrictingType<?>> test4;
                // Interestingly this does succeed
                Wrapper<? extends RestrictingType<?>> test5;
        }
}
```

Compiling this gives the following error:

```
Main.java:23: error: type argument RestrictingType<?> is not within bounds of type-variable T
                Wrapper<RestrictingType<?>> test4;
                                       ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends SelfReferringInterface<T> declared in class Wrapper
1 error
```

Why is `RestrictingType<?>` not within the bounds of `T`? And why is the functionaly similar `? extends RestrictingType<?>` no problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you going to do with this?  I do generics a lot in my code, but I mostly K-I-I-S (keep it simple, s...).  I have learned very well, one fact, which is that Java's Generics are strictly Compile-Time phenomenon for type checking.  At Run-Time generics are **always** istored as Raw Types...  (The class T is "forgotten" - and this is known as "Erasure"). I don't use the question mark operator as you are...  But I think since it would be called "CAP#1" it technically doesn't fit your self-referential "plan"

Comment: @Torelló大哥  A simple example would be an Interface for a tree like structure. The Implementing node type would be the type parameter.
I am well aware that the types are erased at runtime, but this pattern provides enough guarantees compile time that the compiler can insert casts to the appropriate type, so I can use them as such.

Comment: Well...  A "tree of objects" is very common.  The DOM tree, for instance, in HTML.  But why a "Type Tree" that I don't really get...  A self-refferring type...  Hmmm.  I'm going to be wondering about it until somebody posts an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Wrapper<RestrictingType<T>>` works for any given type `T` because we know that `Restricting<T>` implements `SelfReferringInterface<RestrictingType<T>>`. However, `Wrapper<RestrictingType<?>>` does not work because `Restricting<? #1>` may not implement `SelfReferringInterface<RestrictingType<? #2>>`. The wildcard `?` means unknown type, and they may be *two different unknown types* in the two places.

Here is another way to see why this must be: Suppose that your `Wrapper<T>` class can hold multiple items of the wrapped type `T`. Then the bound `<T extends SelfReferringInterface<T>>` means that the type of any one of the items should implement `SelfReferringInterface<type of any other item>`, just like how `class SortedList<T extends Comparable<T>>` means that any one item in the list should be comparable to any other item in the list. However, if you have a `Wrapper<RestrictingType<?>>`, you will be able to add both `RestrictingType<String>` and `RestrictingType<Integer>` items into it, as both those types are subtypes of `RestrictingType<?>`. However, `RestrictingType<String>` does not implement `SelfReferringInterface<RestrictingType<Integer>>`, so the contract is broken.

As to why `Wrapper<? extends RestrictingType<?>>` works, I am not really sure exactly, but the `? extends` wildcard means you cannot add any items into it, so you cannot use it to break the contract.